# swift - Optional to Bool Conversion Causes Error

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble checking if an optional exists or not in swift.

```
var myString:String? = "Hello"

if myString {
    println(myString)
}
```

When I use this code in a playground I get

> note: optional type 'String?' can not be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead
>   if myString {
>      ^
>      (        != nil)

and

> error: type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType.Protocol'
>   if myString

The error suggests I use

```
myString != nil
```

but the documentation says this current code should be OK. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I know if you change your code to read `myString != nil` it will work... the documentation might be out of date?

Comment: @nielsbot Thanks! I updated the Documentation iBook and it seems to now require that you use if(myString !=nil) instead of if(myString).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Xcdoe6-beta5 release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_5_za4gu6/xcode_6_beta_5__release_notes_.pdf)

> Optionals no longer conform to the BooleanType (formerly LogicValue)
> protocol, so they **may no longer be used in place of boolean
> expressions** (they must be explicitly compared with  v != nil). This
> resolves confusion around Bool? and related types, makes code more
> explicit about what test is expected, and is more consistent with the
> rest of the language.
>
> Note that ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional still
> includes some BooleanType functionality. This  issue will be resolved
> in a future beta. (17110911)

So use `myString != nil` as it suggested. And always refer to latest documentation because Swift still in beta stage.